# How do I split an indice of an array into two different pices, I.E to validate that neither number is odd/even?

Tags: java, arrays

I have to check, roomNumber[i], if BOTH numbers (assuming it's two-digit) are not even, and not odd. Only then can I accept the number. Also need to determine if the second digit is not less than double the first. I assume that I need to some how split these into two different ints (a,b), but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you please add more info, see here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @niclaslindgren Well I don't have any code to share. I'm not sure how to code it. The array contains 60 indices.

Comment: @CadeSanders I don't see what your question has to do with arrays. Testing if a number is odd is a question about numbers and operations, not arrays. If that number happens to be in an array, that's an entirely separate issue. Part of learning to write code is learning to break a problem into smaller parts, focusing on the important details and ignoring the unimportant details until later.

Comment: I suggest that you [edit] your question and provide some test cases, i.e. some two digit numbers and indicate which numbers are acceptable and which are not and why.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that you have only two-digit numbers, you can go with it this way:

```
int[] roomNumbers = new int[] { 12, 34, 56, 67, 78 };
for (int num : roomNumbers) {
  int second = num % 10;
  int first = (num - second) / 10;

  System.out.println("first: " + first + " second: " + second);
}
```

You take the second number using the modulo (`%`) operator. To get the first number, you need to subtract the second number and divide it by 10.

Now you can process those numbers further.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions have nothing to do with arrays. Let's reword them:

> How do I test if a number is even?

You can google this and easily find the answer. Hint: use the modulus operator (`%`).

> How do I test if the second digit is not less than double the first digit

Break this into smaller pieces: First you need to separate out the first and second digit. Again, you can google this if you don't know. (Hint: it's very similar to the first question. You can use the `%` operator and division (`/`).

Then you have to compare these according to the rule. Try to write something on your own and see what you can come up with.

Comment: I appreciate the post, It's possible that I didn't explain in enough detail. It DOES have to do with arrays. I know how to identify if a number is even or odd using the modulus operator. I can accept the number if it say, 32, because it's even but one number ISN'T even. I CAN'T accept 44 because BOTH numbers are even. Also, telling me to "google" something isn't very helpful. Obviously I tried that. That's... why I'm here.

Comment: @CadeSanders How does deciding to accept a single number have anything to do with arrays? When you say "one number isn't even", do you mean one *digit*? Again, you need to figure out how to separate the digits of a number to do the comparisons you want. This as nothing to do with arrays.